# Retain all dataframe columns when using spark map

Tags: dataframe, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to expand the body json structure using map (as below), but also need to keep the DateTime column. Currently only the expanded json columns are kept. 
Do you know how to solve this?

```
jsonRdd = df.select(df.DateTime, df.Body.cast("string").alias("json"))

jsonRdd = jsonRdd.rdd.map(lambda x : x.json)

data = spark.read.json(jsonRdd)

display(data)
```

current output looks like :

name    age

j blogg 21

expected output should be :

DateTime name age

4/6/2020 j blogg 21

thank you.

Comment: Hey, could you also add  how your input looks like and the expected output. Sample data will make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: @rupeshreddy, I've added the output to the question. thanks!